# Using Ruby do little changes to run the program

Tags: ruby

For every line of code, a description is given what to do. I have completed half of the program and stuck in `self` object and onwards program so please complete it so that it works.

```
 class Person
  #have a first_name and last_name attribute with public accessors
  #attr_accessor 

  attr_accessor :first_name , :last_name

  #have a class attribute called `people` that holds an array of objects

  @@people = []

  #have an `initialize` method to initialize each instance
  def initialize(first_name,last_name)#should take 2 parameters for first_name and last_name
    @first_name = first_name
    @last_name = last_name      #assign those parameters to instance variables
       #add the created instance (self) to people class variable
  end

  #have a `search` method to locate all people with a matching `last_name`
  def self.search(last_name)
    #accept a `last_name` parameter
    #search the `people` class attribute for instances with the same `last_name`
    #return a collection of matching instances
  end

  #have a `to_s` method to return a formatted string of the person's name
  def to_s
    #return a formatted string as `first_name(space)last_name`
  end
end

p1 = Person.new("John", "Smith")
p2 = Person.new("John", "Doe")
p3 = Person.new("Jane", "Smith")
p4 = Person.new("Cool", "Dude")

puts Person.search("Smith")

# Should print out
# => John Smith
# => Jane Smith
```

Comment: What specifically are you having trouble with?

Comment: add the created self instance to people class variable how to do that

Comment: `@@people << self`

Answer (score 0):

To add the initialized `person` to the class hierarchy variable `@@people` change your `initialize` method to:

```
def initialize(first_name, last_name)
  @first_name = first_name
  @last_name = last_name

  @@people << self
end
```